# How to validate this array in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Client send data in JSON format to server:

```
{
"Product": [{
    "quantity": 4,
    "id": 1
}]
}
```

On the server I tried to validate incoming data using this rule:

```
"Product" => "required|array",
"Product.*.id" => "integer",
"Product.*.quantity" => "integer"
```

Why does it not validate? Where is my mistake?

Comment: That should validate. What validation error are you getting for that JSON?

Comment: I dont get any validation error, but I send incorrect data

Comment: Sorry it works, no matter you send `"quantity": 4` or `"quantity": "4",`

Comment: That's normal. Try `"quantity": "lots"` and you'll likely see it fail validation.

Comment: (See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5f6d9a431c4fcedcbae969ba95d266604be54060/src/Illuminate/Validation/Concerns/ValidatesAttributes.php#L1024 - `return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;`)